# How to use IEDriverServer with Robotframework?

Tags: internet-explorer, robotframework

I use Git Bash on Windows 7 and I want run Robotframework with IEDriverServer.

before run, I set this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/c/workspace/drivers/"
```

My Robotframework conf:

```
Set Environment Variable    no_proxy    127.0.0.1
Set Environment Variable    webdriver.ie.driver  IEDriverServer.exe
Open Browser    ${MY_APP_URL}    ie
```

But I have this error:

```
$ robot tests/5000-foo/5001*.robot
==============================================================================
5001-Search
==============================================================================
foo Home Page - search foo                                           IE_local
InitIE local
| FAIL |
Setup failed:
ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Une connexion existante a d¦ ¦tre ferm¦e par l¦h¦te distant', None, 10054, None))
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5001-Search                                                           | FAIL |
1 critical tests, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 tests total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: What the IE browser version and the Selenium IEDriverServer version? Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140493/ie-browser-nor-working-with-robot-framework) about using Robot with webdriver, you could check it.

Comment: IEDriverServer_x64_3.9.0 and IE 11.0.9600.19266